# how many ways to select three digit number from 1 to 9

Tags: combinatorics

where the second digit is bigger than the first and the third is bigger than the second
ABC 
B IS bigger than A and C is bigger than B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be first to choose 3 different digits from 1 to 9,(we choose different digits because the question says,`first is smaller than second and second than third` therefore they are not equal)
$$=\binom{9}{3}$$
Now as these letters differ in value, we arrange them in decreasing from right to left,

As there is only one way to arrange in such way,
$$=\binom{9}{3}×1$$
And set then as digits of number,

Therefore, total numbers$=\binom{9}{3}$

Comment: how is this code work  
I mean this code n = 10 count = 0 for i in range(n): for j in range(n): for k in range(n): if i < j and j < k: count += 1 print(count)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For a brute force way, consider selecting 3 different numbers from the non-zero digits (how many total selection ways are there?), and then sorting them in descending order (how many selections will produce the same result?).

Now adjust the original selection for producing the same result after sorting.

Comment: I mean this code  n = 10
count = 0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            if i < j and j < k:
                count += 1

print(count)

Comment: @moustafasoama that is correct, but much more of a brute force method than what is being suggested by gt6989b.  There is a simple closed form for the summation you describe involving [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) that gt6989b is trying to give the intuition behind with his answer.

Comment: in this program what the count should be am taking a math course and i can't count those numbers

Comment: I will say it again.  Look into the many different uses and interpretations of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  How many ways can you select three distinct digits from $\{1,2,3,\dots,9\}$ where order doesn't matter?  Having taken three such digits, how many ways can you arrange them in increasing order?

Comment: all possibilities is 9^3 but I have no idea how to arrange them

Comment: what's bring the binomial coefficients here

Comment: @JMoravitz  could you please just tell me how to arrange them

Comment: $9^3$ is the number of three digit numbers which have no zeroes where repetition is allowed.  It is not the number of ways to select three *distinct* digits and further does not take into account whether or not the digits appear in increasing order.  $9\cdot 8\cdot 7$ is the number of ways of selecting three distinct digits, but still without concerning ourselves with whether or not they appear in increasing order.  If we were to count using $9\cdot 8\cdot 7$ and rearranging into increasing order, we will have overcounted every situation six times: e.g. 123,132,213,231,312,321 all give 123

Comment: @moustafasoama If we were to divide by how many times we counted each final outcome, as per the sheperd's principle, we will get $\frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7}{6}$ which you should recognize is precisely equal to $\binom{9}{3}$, the binomial coefficient "9 choose 3," exactly as the other answer already stated and my comments were trying to push you toward

Comment: then how the three nested loops work

Comment: What do you mean "how the three nested loops work"?  You should already know that it works... it is merely counting how many triples there are by going through them each one by one and seeing if it should be counted by brute force.  If you are asking why these different methods give the same answer, it follows from the principle of [counting in two ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)).

Comment: the loops iterate over all the possibilities 9^3 including repetition and unordered so if n=1000 the code become too slow i want to know where is the arrangement part in the code